# HttpContext.Current.Items appears to be shared between requests - SignalR issue maybe?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I am trying to write some logging code in an ActionFilter to determine how long some actions take to process. The code looks something like this:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.Start();
    HttpContext.Current.Items.Add("Stopwatch", stopwatch);
}

public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
{    
    var stopwatch = HttpContext.Current.Items["Stopwatch"] as Stopwatch;

    if (stopwatch != null)
    {
        stopwatch.Stop();
        var millis = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        // Code to log here
    }
}
```

It is configured here in `FilterConfig.cs`

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{            
    filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    filters.Add(new LogRequestMetricFilter());
}
```

And is configured in Autofac for property injection here:

```
 builder.Register(c => new LogRequestMetricFilter()).PropertiesAutowired()
    .AsActionFilterFor<Controller>().InstancePerRequest();
```

This is mostly working fine, however in some cases when `HttpContext.Current.Items.Add("Stopwatch", stopwatch);` is called an error is thrown

> Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'Stopwatch'  Key being added: 'Stopwatch'

This would imply that the `HttpContext.Current` is being shared between requests. This seems to happen on methods with SignalR but as far as I can tell they have completed at this point, and it shouldn't share the `HttpContext` anyway.

Can anyone explain why `OnActionExecuting` is called when there is already an Item with that Key in the Items Dictionary

Comment: As an aside, I have fixed the exception by calling `HttpContext.Current.Items.Remove("Stopwatch");` in `OnActionExecuted` but I am still curious as to how it was caused in the first place

Comment: @ste-fe I suggest a configuration mistake. Can you show your startup?

Comment: @tester Startup? This is not a netcore application.

Comment: @ste-fe: Where do you configure the filter

Comment: @Tester In AppStart.FilterConfig.cs

Comment: @ste-fe: Show it pls. And also whole filter (with attribute ...) You haven't configuret it twice ? Sorry for bad questing, sometimes it are the simples things.

Comment: @Tester - added fitler config and autofac injection

Comment: When running SignalR commands from JavaScript, if can come through the same connection already established, which perhaps is why you see it already exist?  You could test this by temporarily setting SingalR to use only longpolling.